# ELK stack on google compute engine

Tags: elasticsearch, google-compute-engine, kibana

Trying to set up an ELK stack on a google compute engine server I found out that the ["click to deploy" solution google is providing](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/solution/click-to-deploy-images/elasticsearch?q=elasticsearch) is outdated.

None the less I tried installing Logstash and Kibana on top of the ES only to find out that I could not connect to Kibana (although I had no problem connecting to the elasticsearch itself both from inside google compute and the outside world).

Having the ELK stack already working on an AWS Ububnu 14.04 machine, I thought I'll try to start for a fresh machine and install everything myself on google compute.

After installing ES I again found that I could not connect to ES from outside (on the default port 9200, that of course worked with the click-to-deploy).

It's worth noting here that the click-to-deploy servers where probably intended for internal use, because they had ephemeral IPs, while I defined all my machines with static IPs (testing around this subject was a dead end as well).

In all cases the result for my servers was the same - the error I got was ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

This (surprisingly) led me to think I was missing some firewall definition.

1. I tried opening a different port and listening on it on the server side with `netcat -lp <some-port>`
2. I then tried to run from my remote machine the same request I would run on elastic, but on the new port: `curl -X GET 'http://<static-ip>:<some-port>'`
3. The request went on with no problems
4. I stopped elasticsearch and started `netcat -lp 9200`
5. `curl -X GET 'http://<static-ip>:9200'` from the remove machine came through like a charm.

   Even after opening the relevant ports for all machines and repeating the entire process (with all the different combinations) I realized I am probably missing something else.

Compering to the best of my ability with the google instance was yet another dead end.

What am I missing here? is there another connectivity definition in ES or GCE?

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your firewall rules and your routes setup in compute engine? Mh but since you tested with curl and netcat already. Have you checked with `netstat -tulpen` whether your service is listening on the correct interface? It might listen on an unrouted interface (lo?)

Answer (score 1):

Well, [konqi](https://serverfault.com/users/322894/konqi) was sort of right. The problem was ES connecting to the loopback device, but setting `network.bind_host` to `_non_loopback_` is only half of the solution, I can now acsess ES only form the outside (of course).

Apparently, there is a GCE plugin to fix this, but only up to ES version 1.7, guess I'll have to wait for it to catch up. The rest can be hacked around.